# Doing system administration tasks with a Python/Django via a web interface

Tags: python, django, linux, system-administration

I have just started learning [Django](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29) and my main aim is to build a company intranet website where I can do system administration things like backups, restore, etc.

I have found various Django tutorials about general web sites, but I could not find any tutorials / links where some have thought about doing system administration things via a web interface.

How can I use models / views and integrate with Python functions?

Comment: Authentication is the major concern for any systems administration automation that's made accessible via a web front end.  That's true regardless of the web programming technologies or frameworks involved.  It's essentially the same problem regardless of whether you're using simple, old-fashioned CGI or the latest Django with the slickest AJAX components.

How much do you trust the authentication that passed through your browser and your web server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is to do administration tasks then I suggest using [webmin](http://www.webmin.com/). If you just want to do this to learn [Django](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29)/[Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) then feel free to use the functionality of webmin as a guide. Think about all the steps involved in taking backups, moving files around and other administration tasks. This should help you understand the problem better and break it into manageable chunks.

Remember that Django is really just Python underneath, and it can be a vastly powerful tool. Try looking at some of your Python scripts that you use for systems administration. Maybe you can adapt those as a web interface.

Comment: I want code myself and learn. Is webmin coded in python?? I have already 4-5 scripts working in python. but i am bit confused about how get those data from view to template. i know its not difficult but to start with if i can get any ready to use script i can see how he is passong variables / values from models , bviews to template

Comment: Consider building a blog with the framework and look at some general tutorials on the framework. Usually any code that does work on data goes in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

As Devin M says, Django is 'just Python' in the backend (that is, the functions your views call), so if you really wanted to, you could use a library like [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.0.1/index.html) to invoke system administration actions without needing your web server to have direct access to the infrastructure.

Answer (score 1):

[Ansible](http://www.ansibleworks.com/) does what you describe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python ([Django](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29)) + SSH for doing all the system administration tasks. At my place, we built a web custom computer monitoring system with a system administration capability.

All you need is basically setting up a password-less SSH connection for each server. We chose to use the SSH key method. All system administration tasks were executed using SSH, for example `ssh user@server1 'sh backupall.sh'`. All that was left was creating a Python (Django) application which executes all these SSH commands.